# How i can refresh chart without refresh page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, chart.js

I want to refresh chart without refresh.
I use setTimeout function, but when i apply to chart, dataset refresh only when reloading pages..

This function chart...

```
$(function () {
        var areaChartData = {
            labels  : ['Goods', 'Qty'],
            datasets: [
            {
                label               : '>30 Days',
                backgroundColor     : 'red',
                borderColor         : 'red',
                pointRadius          : false,
                pointColor          : 'red',
                pointStrokeColor    : 'red',
                pointHighlightFill  : 'red',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'red',
                data                : [setTimeout(reload(), 5000), 21] 
            },
            {
                label               : '15-30 Days',
                backgroundColor     : 'orange',
                borderColor         : 'orange',
                pointRadius         : false,
                pointColor          : 'orange',
                pointStrokeColor    : 'orange',
                pointHighlightFill  : 'orange',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'orange',
                data                : [setTimeout(reload(), 5000), 22]
            }
            ]
        }
})
```

this jquery function...

```
function reload() {
        var temp;

        $.ajax({
            type  : 'ajax',
            url   : '<?= base_url()?>Dashboard/test',
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                temp = data;
            }
        })

        return temp;
        setTimeout(reload, 5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement is before your `setTimeout` call.  I would also recommend to not use ajax synchronously, as this will block your UI and possibly cause it to hang every 5 seconds.

You should separate your function calls to a format like this if possible:

```
$(function() {
  function bindChart(data) {
    var config = buildChartConfiguration(data);

    // bind configuration & data to chart here
    // $('#chart').plot(config)  or whatever your library's syntax is
  }

  function buildChartConfiguration(data) {
     return {
            labels  : ['Goods', 'Qty'],
            datasets: [
            {
                label               : '>30 Days',
                backgroundColor     : 'red',
                borderColor         : 'red',
                pointRadius          : false,
                pointColor          : 'red',
                pointStrokeColor    : 'red',
                pointHighlightFill  : 'red',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'red',
                data                : [data, 21] 
            },
            {
                label               : '15-30 Days',
                backgroundColor     : 'orange',
                borderColor         : 'orange',
                pointRadius         : false,
                pointColor          : 'orange',
                pointStrokeColor    : 'orange',
                pointHighlightFill  : 'orange',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'orange',
                data                : [data, 22]
            }
            ]
        }
  }

  function loadData() {
     $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url   : '<?= base_url()?>Dashboard/test',
        dataType : 'json'
     })
     .then(bindChart)
     .then(function() {
        // on completion request new data in 5s
        setTimeout(loadData, 5000);
     });
  }

  // load data from server
  loadData();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
 $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url   : '<?= base_url()?>Dashboard/test',
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            areaChartData.datasets[0].data = data;
            areaChartData.datasets[1].data = data;

        }
    })
```

and then your have to set settimeout to function which give you ajax response data and set default data of dataset with some value.